# uncompressed quicktime export options

Tags: export

Trying to export uncompressed quicktime movies in 2.79 and I could really use some help.  I can seem to figure out the new export options to do this as I've always done in versions below 2.79.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks 
[image]

Comment: What's the reason to encode *uncompressed*?

Comment: so I can choose my encoding codec(s) based on my needs at a later time. (usually ProRes variant)

Comment: There are many reasons (flexibility, file size, color management etc.) to save your animation as image sequence (preferably exr) and encode that to prores or dnxhd... @sean

Comment: true but I like to do my compositing in blender from image sequences after I render the images, so the way you mention I'd then have to render the composite to images (2nd render) and then convert my images to ProRes etc as a 3rd render.  I'd much prefer to do as before and render my compositor animation to an uncompressed format as my master file and then encode in another app, based on my desired formats.